# Why $\lim_{n \to \infty} n\int_{x}^{x+\frac{1}{n}} F(u)du - n\int_{a}^{a+\frac{1}{n}} F(u)du = F(x)-F(a)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

In a proof I'm reading, there's the following statement:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n\int_{x}^{x+\frac{1}{n}} F(u)du - n\int_{a}^{a+\frac{1}{n}} F(u)du = F(x)-F(a)$$

where $$F(x) := \int_a^x f(u)du$$

and $f$ is bounded and $L-B$ (Lebesgue-Borel) measurable.

I cannot see how the author reached this conclusion.
I have tried splitting the first integral to be written as such:

$$ n\int_{x}^{x+\frac{1}{n}} F(u)du = n\int_{a}^{x+\frac{1}{n}} F(u)du - n\int_{a}^{x} F(u)du$$

which, at the limit, is actually $F'(x)$, which doesn't seem to get me any closer to obtaining the equation.

Another attempt is observing that this last split equals:

$$n \Big( \int_{a}^{x+\frac{1}{n}} F(u)du - \int_{a}^{x} F(u)du \Big ) $$

which at the limit gives:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} n \cdot \Big( \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{a}^{x+\frac{1}{n}} F(u)du - \int_{a}^{x} F(u)du \Big ) $$
$$= \lim_{n\to \infty} n \cdot \Big( \int_{a}^{x} F(u)du - \int_{a}^{x} F(u)du \Big )  = 0$$

which also must be a mistake.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Forget where $F$ came from and just use the fact that it is continuous.  If you are still stuck consider $F$ to be constant  and check why that works. (in small intervals continuous functions are kind of constant.)

Comment: The source of the confusion is that the integrand is capital $F$, where typically it is lower case $f$ and the indefinite integral is $F$. You are correct that in the limit, the difference quotient converges to the derivative of the indefinite integral, which is $F(x)$. Same with the second integral. It's just a notation thing.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson For the constant it indeed works out using the integration definition of a simple function, but I'm still having trouble with formally applying it to $F$. I have now tried defining $G(x):=\int_a^x F(x)$ in the hopes of using $G$'s continuity somehow, but I just don't see how this helps. Also $F$'s continuity doesn't seem to help. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've added another attempt, which also must be wrong, but I don't see why :/

Comment: Can't the 'Mean value theorem' be applied here?  $\int_x^{x+1/n}F(u)du = F(c)/n$ for some $c \in [x, x+1/n]$.

Comment: In the statement you want to prove treat the two parts separately and, as @Guangliang indicated here, apply the mean-value theorem for integrals.  This is way simpler than you imagine.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson Even so - why is my second attempt (see my edit) wrong? Will try your suggestion anyway - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Seven comments so far, time to get explicit with the assistance.*

You want to prove this fact about this sequence:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n\int_{c}^{c+\frac{1}{n}} g(x)\,dx  = g(c) \tag{*}$$
assuming only that $g$ is continuous   on some interval $[c,c+1]$.

Your attempts to prove the bigger statment led you to miss this simpler reason why it all works.  Your second edit with two separate limits as $n\to\infty$?  What can I say? Don't do that!

**Idea 1.**  The mean value theorem for integrals [see comment by @Guangliang] allows you to  claim that for each $n$ there is a point $c_n$ so that $c\leq c_n \leq c + \frac1n$
$$ \int_{c}^{c+\frac{1}{n}} g(x)\,dx  = g(c_n)([c+\frac1n]- c) = \frac1n g(c_n).$$
Since $c_n\to c$ and $g$ is continuous, you know that $g(c_n)\to g(c)$ and you can establish (*).

**Idea 2.**  Forgot the mean-value theorem?  Or bigger fan of the fundamental theorem?

Set it up this way:  $G(t) = \int_c^t g(x)\,dx$ and hence $G'(c)=g(c)$ because of continuity of $g$.

$$ n\int_{c}^{c+\frac{1}{n}} g(x)\,dx = n[G(c+\frac1n)-G(c)] = \frac{G(c+\frac1n)-G(c)}{\frac1n} \to G'(c)$$
as $n\to\infty$ by the definition of derivative and again   you can establish (*).

**Note.**  The first method, using the mean-value theorem, is available here since $g$ is continuous.  The seond idea does not need continuity and depends only on $g$ being   integrable in some sense on $[c,c+1]$ and on $g$ being continuous at the point $c$.

**Postscript.**  By the way, students often stare hard and confused at the limit
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty}  \frac{G(x+\frac1n)-G(x)}{\frac1n}  .$$
Ideally you glance briefly and recognize immediately that must be $G'(x)$ if that derivative exists.  It allows you to see easily that if $G$ is differentiable then $g(x)=G'(x)$ is the pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions, i.e., derivatives belong to the first class of Baire.  That is an important first step in understanding derivatives.

Comment: Fantastic! The first option is what I would have to go for in this case, since this is part of the proof of the FTC, so option 2 is not available to me for this purpose. I'll just add that I figured out why the limit of the products I wrote is not the product of the limits - that is because it may be the case that one is infinite and the other is 0 (in which case it would be incorrect to do that transition). Thanks!

Comment: @Anon The FTC is available to you in this case since the function $F$ you are working with is continuous and so you can use what you learned in freshman calculus.